# Updating a transfered iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, publishing, application-loader

Last week we've [transferred a published app in iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) to another company's account. Now they want us to provide an update to the app.

How do we sign, package and submit the app to them for publishing? Which Provisioning profile do we need to use? Do we still sign the .ipa with our team and send the .ipa to them or do we need to have additional info for this to work?

I hope someone is able to shed some light on this process, since the whole provisioning and signing process is hard to grasp for me.

Comment: You should be using the new Developer Account for another company to create new certificates, profiles etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently we have transferred our app to another company and we have pushed an update to the app. Let me explain you how we did

1. Once you transfer the app to another company account, you will not
   be able to use your old certificates for publishing any new update
   for app.
2. Apple by default removes your certificates and appid from your
   previous account.
3. Apple generates an app id for your app in transferred account.
4. You can use this app id and create new certificate for your app and
   publish the app by using new account.

Comment: So basically I need access to their account in order to upload an update? Or is there a way to give them an IPA for them to publish? I just don't want to send them our source code, and they don't want to give us their credentials.

Comment: In our case they gave us their credentials to upload the app to appstore. I think if you want to generate the ipa then you need the new certificate and their credentials mapped with your xcode. As they are not ready to provide you the details, you need to ask them to provide some role to you so that you can upload the app from your end. You can check this link about roles https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html @handyface

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the certificate and the private keys used to signe the application.

You import the private keys on your computer and install the certificate.
Then get the corresponding profile, compile, sign and post.

**The other solution** is to regenerate a new certificat with the keys on your computer, a new provisionning profile.

Then sign the app with those new files.

*The certificate and profile need to be created from the new account.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note that we've submitted and published the app on our account before. Can I simply use my existing keys to sign the application and send the ipa to them? Are they still valid after the transfer?

Comment: You have to re create certificates and provisional profile again from new account

Comment: Can I use their 'production' provisioning profile to supply them the IPA, after which they can sign and submit the application via application loader?

Comment: No because the provisionning profile is linked to the certificate